# onclick button affecting other element

Tags: javascript

I'm am just starting to learn Javascript but I noticed that when I click the button suddenly activates the other elements instead of what it's supposed to do, like for example whenever I click the Address button where it is supposed to drop down an input box alert it triggers the the age input but both of them works fine when alone

```html
<html>
<body>
<input id="age" value="18.5" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">BMI</button>

<p id="BMI"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var age, voteable; 
  age = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);
  if (isNaN(age)) {
   voteable = "Invalid Entry";
} else {
  document.getElementById("BMI").innerHTML = voteable + " to be vaccinated.";
  voteable = (age < 18.5) ? "Ideal":"Overweight";
  document.getElementById("BMI").innerHTML = voteable + " to be vaccinated.";
  voteable = (age > 25) ? "Overweight":"Ideal";
  document.getElementById("BMI").innerHTML = voteable + " to be vaccinated.";}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Address</button>
<p id="demo_123">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var person = prompt("Please enter your Address:");
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "Please fill out the Address.";
  } else {
    txt = "Your Address: " + person + ", Thank You for filling it out!";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo_123").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66829832/10233884. Let me know if you want more clarification

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes from the fact that you provided the same function `myFunction()` to both `onclick` listeners. Because of that, the first button refers to the wrong `myFunction()`. The function called is your second `myFunction()` because the second declaration redefines this function.

In order to prevent this, you should define 2 functions **with different names** so the `onclick` listeners won't refer to the same function anymore and the first function won't be redefined.

```html
<html>
<body>
<input id="age" value="18.5" />

<button onclick="ageFunction()">BMI</button>

<p id="BMI"></p>

<script>
function ageFunction() {
  var age, voteable; 
  age = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);
  if (isNaN(age)) {
   voteable = "Invalid Entry";
} else {
  document.getElementById("BMI").innerHTML = voteable + " to be vaccinated.";
  voteable = (age < 18.5) ? "Ideal":"Overweight";
  document.getElementById("BMI").innerHTML = voteable + " to be vaccinated.";
  voteable = (age > 25) ? "Overweight":"Ideal";
  document.getElementById("BMI").innerHTML = voteable + " to be vaccinated.";}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

<html>
<body>
<button onclick="addressFunction()">Address</button>
<p id="demo_123">
<script>
function addressFunction() {
  var txt;
  var person = prompt("Please enter your Address:");
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "Please fill out the Address.";
  } else {
    txt = "Your Address: " + person + ", Thank You for filling it out!";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo_123").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes rename your functions so that it describes what they do. This way you will identify them faster and you will affect them exactly where you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same function name **myFunction**, however, you can still use the same function name by passing an argument. For example:

```html
   <button onclick="myFunction('Age')">BMI</button>
   <button onclick="myFunction('Address')">Address</button>
```

and in your Script:

```js
     function myFunction(parameter) {
       if (parameter === "Age") {
           var age, voteable; 
           age = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);
           if (isNaN(age)) {
               voteable = "Invalid Entry";
              } else {
               document.getElementById("BMI").innerHTML = voteable + " to 
               be vaccinated.";
               voteable = (age < 18.5) ? "Ideal":"Overweight";
               document.getElementById("BMI").innerHTML = voteable + " to 
               be vaccinated.";
               voteable = (age > 25) ? "Overweight":"Ideal";
               document.getElementById("BMI").innerHTML = voteable + " to 
               be vaccinated.";}
             }
           } else if (parameter === "Address") {
             var txt;
             var person = prompt("Please enter your Address:");
             if (person == null || person == "") {
                txt = "Please fill out the Address.";
             } else {
                txt = "Your Address: " + person + ", Thank You for filling 
                it out!";
             }
             document.getElementById("demo_123").innerHTML = txt;
           }
         }
```